# DataWeave: Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor when parsing a String to DateTime

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave, anypoint-studio, mule4

I have a problem with DataWeave 2 transformation. I have:

```
var parseDate = (dateStr) -> dateStr as DateTime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd"}
```

But when I am running this code I get:

> Caused by: org.mule.runtime.api.el.ExpressionExecutionException:
> Cannot coerce String (2019-03-26) to DateTime, caused by: Text
> '2019-03-26' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from
> TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 2019-03-26 of type
> java.time.format.Parsed

I am using `DateTime` cause it is detected as such when creating metadata. But the class itself has `LocalDate bookingDate;` - the problem is that when I am trying to use `LocalDate` - I get an error:

```
Unable to resolve reference of: `LocalDate`.
```

What can I do with this problem? Can I parse it somehow correctly? Or what can I do with the `LocalDate` problem mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

As your input string has only the date part, you can use the following DataWeave expression:

```
var parseDate = (dateStr) -> dateStr as Date {format: "yyyy-MM-dd"}
```

Comment: This time I get `Caused by: org.mule.runtime.api.el.ExpressionExecutionException: Unable to convert '2019-03-26T16:45:22.146+01:00' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.time.LocalDateTime'`

Comment: Could you please provide the actual dateStr value that you have in your payload? Do you have more than one date / date time field? Could you have one field that is just a date (without the time part) and another that has the date and time parts?